# What happens to the soul when someone commit suicide?

Tags: karma, atma, rebirth, jiva

1. What happens to the soul when one commits suicide?
2. Does the rebirth takes instantly?
3. Do the suicide soul try to make contact with family and friends?
4. Is it true that the suicide soul has to stay in between till the age he was destined to live on Earth?

   For eg if he was destined to live for 70 years on Earth but he took away his live at the age of 30 so does he has to live for 40 years in between.

Comment: Generally if one ends his life by himself before allotted Karma for that Atma in a body is complete, he doesnt to upper lokas immediately....

Comment: For eg if he was destined to live for 70 years on Earth but he took away his live at the age of 30 so does he has to live for 40 years in between. - mostly true.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Untimely death, heaven/hell, ghosts and rebirth](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9655/5212) and [Does re-birth take place immediately after death according to Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3925/5212)

Comment: dhandukari story mentioned by sage vyasa tells about that it relieves the sprit of prethathva.. and progress to next stage seven days srimad bhagavata sravana should be done by learned brahmin in the home of deceased

Answer (score 3):

According to Parashara Smriti Chapter 4 verses, given below, such a soul remains in hell for 60 thousand years. So, immediate rebirth is out of consideration.

> The fate, which a man or woman comes by after having committed suicide
>   by hanging, either out of inordinate pride, uncurable love, or
>   excessive fright or anger, will be presently described.
>
> For a period of sixty thousand years, the spirit of a suicide is
>   consigned to the darkness of a hell, which is full of blood and fetid
>   pus.
>
> **Chapter 4, Sloka 1 & 2.**

[image]

The subsequent verses say that no period of impurity should be observed in case of such a death and also that no libations of water (Tarpana) must be performed.